# How to use both IHttpClientFactory and Typed HttpClient?

Tags: asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

I have a typed HttpClient and (let's say) another service/class that uses IHttpClientFactory to get a HttpClient instance.

To register IHttpClientFactory, I inject it as `services.AddHttpClient()`. And to register typed clients, I go with `services.AddHttpClient<MyTypedClient>`

My question is, do you think there will be a problem if I use both of the use cases. Any impact on HttpMessageHandler pool?

Thanks,
Cem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply, no. You can use whatever you want. `IHttpClientFactory` handles the collection of `HttpMessageHandler` instances. When you inject a typed client, what's actually happening is that `IHttpClientFactory` is invoked, and new `HttpClient` instance is created, and its handler is set to the either an already created `HttpMessageHandler` instance or a new instance.

In other words, it's mostly syntactic sugar. `IHttpClientFactory` is invoked in either case, and it always creates a new `HttpClient` instance, setting the handler to one that's tracking, based on name. A "typed" client is really just a "named" client, with the type as the name, and all clients are in effect "named" because it's all being stored in a `ConcurrentDictionary`, where the name is the key.